# Is there a way to mock Parse.com response in order to use them in unit testing for iOS?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, parse-platform, stubs

I will use `Nimbleparse` as backend and I'm writing tests in my iOS project using the [parse-SDK-ios](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX). Is there a way to simulate responses, for example when I try to signin a `PFUser`? Like using stubs for common `http` requests.

Thank you